# Getting file size in Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am using gstreamer to implement an audio player. I have created pipeline as below:

```
filesrc location=a.mp3 ! mymp3parser ! mymp3dec ! alsasink.
```

I want to use the size of the file in bytes (i.e a.mp3 file size) in mymp3parser plugin. But I haven't got any clue to get the file size. How do I get the file size in mymp3parser from filesrc?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a duration query to the filesrc. The query can specify the format (e.g. time or bytes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With the query function using bytes format, I am able to get the ize